# ¿Cómo ordeno un array de objetos en Javascript?

Tags: javascript

Tengo este objeto:

```
[{"name": "17:00-20:00"}, {"name": "9:00-12:00"}]
```

¿Cómo hago para ordenarlo por la clave `name` de forma que ascendente?

Comment: Agrega lo intentado al momento por favor, lee [ask]

Answer (score 2):

Javascript permite ordenar cadenas de texto tomando la cadena como valores numéricos directamente cuando sea necesario (javascript lo hace directamente cuando se interpreta que es necesario y se puede hacer la conversión), sin embargo esto no es lo adecuado para tu caso, ya que muchas vecez puede pasar que debido a como esta formado el orden de por ejemplo tu fecha, habrá siempre inconsistencias entre el valor numérico formado por las cadenas de fecha.

Por este motivo, es mejor hacer este ordenamiento por partes (no tomar la cadena entera si no ordenarlo de acuerdo a partes de la cadena).

El formato que estas usando no parece una fecha si no mas bien un rango de horas, es decir, de una hora a otra, así que será mas facil, checa lo siguiente:

```
"name": "17:00-20:00"
```

Vemos que tienes una separación entre una hora y otra, esta separación es el simbolo (-), donde la primera parte debe o debería indicar el inicio y la segunda el final, entonces podemos aprovecharnos de esto y usar la función `sort` de los arreglos para poder ordenarlos de acuerdo a la fecha de inicio en orden de menor a mayor, para ello debemos primero extraer solo la primera parte de la hora, que sería el punto de inicio, esto se puede hacer con la función `split`, vamos entonces a mostrar el ordenamiento con la función sort de tu objeto:

```js
const objeto = [{"name": "17:00-20:00"}, {"name": "9:00-12:00"}];
const objetoOrdenado = objeto.sort((a, b)=>{
    return parseFloat(a.name.split("-")[0].split(":").join(".")) < parseFloat(b.name.split("-")[0].split(":").join(".")) ? -1 : 1;
});

console.log(objetoOrdenado);
```

Como vemos es muy sencillo, solo debemos usar la función sort, ahora bien, lo que si depronto no ha de ser facil entender es hacer tantas operaciones juntas, por ejemplo:

```
parseFloat(a.name.split("-")[0].split(":").join(".")) < parseFloat(b.name.split("-")[0].split(":").join(".")) ? -1 : 1;
```

En pocas palabras eso de arriba se llama shorthand if y permite hacer una condicional corta, en donde el valor devuelto en este caso siempre será ya sea 1 o -1, no puede ser ningún otro ya que le espeficicamos fue esos dos valores.

Lo que se hace es primero al resultado de la operación, convertirlo a flotante:

```
parseFloat(...cosas);
```

Dentro de parseFloat tenemos:

```
a.name.split("-")[0].split(":").join(".")
```

Donde `a` es un parametro que nos da la función `sort`, `a` en este caso nos indica el primer elemento del arreglo hasta el penultimo (a cambia su valor dependiendo de cuál es el que se este recorriendo), para la primera iteración `a` seria igual a :

```
{"name": "17:00-20:00"};
```

así que a nuestro objeto `a` estamos accediendo a su propiedad `name` y como name contiene una cadena de texto, podemos usar la función split, que lo que hace es devolvernos un arreglo partiendo la cadena en algún caracter, me explico, si tenemos:

```
"17:00-20:00"
```

Y le decimos a la función `split` que nos parta la cadena haciendo uso del caracter (-) entonces el resultado sería algo así:

```
["17:00", "20:00"]
```

Ahora bien, nosotros solo necesitamos comparar la primera parte, que es la hora de inicio, así que accedemos al primer elemento:

```
a.name.split("-")[0]
```

Y luego volvemos a hacer un split, pero esta vez usando (:) para partir la cadena:

```
a.name.split("-")[0].split(":")
```

Esto nos devolvería lo siguiente:

```
["17", "00"]
```

Bien, justo lo que queremos, la hora y los minutos de nuestro inicio en un arreglo, ahora lo que hacemos es unirlos de nuevo como cadena de texto usando la función `join` (lo hacemos para que el numero luego pueda ser convertido a flotante, y para esto debemos unirlo con un punto), quedando el resultado de esto:

```
a.name.split("-")[0].split(":").join(".")
```

Algo como esto:

```
"17.00"
```

Ahora que ya tenemos un formato valido para usar la función parseFloat nos queda de la siguiente manera:

```
parseFloat(a.name.split("-")[0].split(":").join("."))
```

El resultado es el numero 17

Ahora bien, esto no es todo, ya que debemos comparar cual fecha entre la actual (a) y cual fecha entre la siguiente es mayor (b), por lo que debemos hacer esto mismo con `b`, donde `b` representa siempre el siguiente valor a `a`:

```
parseFloat(b.name.split("-")[0].split(":").join("."))
```

Si unimos estos dos y comprobamos cuál es mayor, nos queda la condición asi:

```
parseFloat(a.name.split("-")[0].split(":").join(".")) < parseFloat(b.name.split("-")[0].split(":").join("."))
```

Que se traduciria simplemente a:

```
17 < 9
```

En caso de que `a < b` sea cierto, es decir 17 sea menor a 9 significa que esta mal ordenado, por lo que debe ser ordenado, para ordenarlo de menor a mayor deberemos retornar `-1` para mayor a menor deberemos retornar `1`, para no hacer nada debemos retornar `0`, quedando entonces todo como:

```
parseFloat(a.name.split("-")[0].split(":").join(".")) < parseFloat(b.name.split("-")[0].split(":").join(".")) ? -1 : 1;
```

Esto se traduce a : 'Si a < b pon -1 si a >= b pon 1', de esta manera funciona nuestro ejemplo con nuestra función sort personalizada.

Entonces así es como le diriamos correctamente a la función sort que nos ordene nuestro arreglo de objetos de acuerdo a la clave `name` y en tu caso tambien de acuerdo a la hora de inicio.